# JSON file array discord.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, discord.js

i want the user when take the role , the bot send to him 1 line from the lines in json file but it send all lines i just want in order one by one like if he take the role first time the bot send uncle if he take the role again bot send dad etc..[my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR5bX.png)

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
      if (!oldMember.roles.cache.has("933027660894994504") && newMember.roles.cache.has("933027660894994504")) {
        fs.readFile('msgs.json', (err, data) => {
          if (err) { throw err; }
          const msgsJson = require("./msgs.json");
          newMember.send(msgsJson.name);
          console.log(msgsJson.name)
        });
        
     
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the first element of the array like this:

```
msgsJson.name[0]
```

As arrays start at 0. You can also pick a random one like so:

```
msgsJson.name[Math.floor(Math.random()*msgsJson.name.length)];
```

I recommend you read up on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp.